# Is this the correct way to say "I practice Chinese with my friend"?

Tags: translation

Is "我习说中文一起我的朋友" the correct way to say "I practice speaking Chinese with my friend"?

Comment: No, it should be `我和我的朋友练习中文。`

Answer (score 3):

Nope. The correct statement is: （我）跟我的朋友一起练习说汉语

This is because Chinese is an SVO language, and we have:

- 我 subject 1 (S1)
- 跟 conjunction (&)
- 我的朋友 subject 2 (S2)
- 一起 adverb (A)
- 练习 auxilliary verb (aux)
- 说 verb (V)
- 汉语 object (O)

Syntax: S1 & S2 A aux V O

Comment: I had a feeling I was wrong, thank you for the help!

Comment: some users would question ＂练习 auxilliary verb (aux)＂，according to e。g。使用现代汉语语法，Chinese has the following 能愿动词：要、想、愿意、肯、敢、应该、应当、应、该、得（dei３）、能、能够、可以、可、准、许、得（得２）、配、值得、可能、会。
according to the usual grammars 练习 is not considered an auxiliary verb （能愿动词 or 助动词）。

Comment: You can also treat it as a compund verb V + V, if you will.

Comment: 练习 of course by itself is a compound word （合成词）（in fact compound verb）of the 并列 （parallel） type combining the ２ verbs 练 and 习 with identical or similar meanings， as far as its relation to the following verb 说 is concerned，grammars would say 练习 has the verb 说 as its object，in fact 练习 appears to belong to both the 体宾动词 and the 谓宾动词 type， i。e。能带体词宾语又能带谓词宾语，you can say e。g。 练习汉语习语和名言口译技巧 and 练习空手道（examples from iciba），therefore 练习汉语 also seems possible besides 练习说汉语etc。

Comment: as far as S－V－O， some users would propose the following： 我（S）练习（V）说汉语（O）where O is a V－O phrase 说（V）汉语（O）cf。外国人实用汉语语法